# How to merge pandas dataframe passing a lambda as first parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, chaining

Restricting to pandas method chaining, how to apply merge method using last dataframe state with lambda function without using pipe?

The code below works. But it depends on the pipe method.

```py
(pd.DataFrame(
    [{'YEAR':2013,'FK':1, 'v':1},
     {'YEAR':2013,'FK':2, 'v':2},
     {'YEAR':2014,'FK':1, 'v':3},
     {'YEAR':2014,'FK':2, 'v':4}
    ])
  .pipe(lambda w: w.merge(w.query('YEAR==2013')[['FK','v']],
        on='FK',
        how='left'
       ))
)
```

The code below doesn't work.

```py
(pd.DataFrame(
    [{'YEAR':2013,'FK':1, 'v':1},
     {'YEAR':2013,'FK':2, 'v':2},
     {'YEAR':2014,'FK':1, 'v':3},
     {'YEAR':2014,'FK':2, 'v':4}
    ])
 .merge(lambda w: w.query('YEAR==2013'),
        on='FK',
        how='left'
       )
)
```

Return:
`TypeError: Can only merge Series or DataFrame objects, a <class 'function'> was passed`

Comment: You can't, this is precisely why the `pipe` method exists. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: just to challenge the limits of my knowledge frontier in pandas. Thanks for sharing your vision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, this is precisely why the [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) method exists.

For completeness, DataFrame methods/accessors that accept a callable (as primary parameter and as of pandas 2.0.3) are:

- [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)/[`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
- [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)/[`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)
- [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
- [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)/[`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

For other cases, you need to use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html).